# Getting 403 Error: Apache2 mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mongodb, apache, virtualhost, wsgi

Me, and a friend of mine are facing a problem getting a raw entity of [PI Joule's @channel (Link to "Production" Readme)](https://github.com/PiJoules/atchannel/blob/master/PRODUCTION.md) to work, currently supposed to be running at the domain atchannel.cf, as per the person's guide to set it up, as well as do what it said in the main README file [here](https://github.com/PiJoules/atchannel/blob/master/README.md)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName atchannel.cf
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www-atchannel/atchannel.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www-atchannel>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www-atchannel/atchannel/static
    <Directory /var/www-atchannel/atchannel/static/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errorAtChannel.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/accessAtChannel.log combined


 </VirtualHost>
```

This is the Apache Virtual Host for the file, which matches up with the path to the site, but still returns a 403 forbidden error. Can anyone tell us what we're doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<Directory /var/www-atchannel/atchannel/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

you should have:

```
<Directory /var/www-atchannel>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The directory didn't match the leading path for where the WSGI script file is located.

Comment: Was Apache restarted? What URL are you using to access the site? Are you using the hostname, or an IP address in the URL?

Comment: Apache wasn't restarted at that point in time, but trying once I noticed your reply sees nothing. We're using http://atchannel.cf to access the site.

Comment: If you have the VirtualHost definition in a file by itself, add a syntax error to it and try and restart Apache to see if it fails. A line with 'xxx' by itself on it is enough. This will validate that the file is being used. With the correction I can't really see anything else obvious, so only other thing can think of is that that virtual host has been enabled and Apache isn't using it.

Comment: It seems that apache is indeed using it. Apache fails to start properly when adding in a syntax error, however, starts again when I remove said syntax error

Comment: Do you have any other VirtualHost with the same ServerName?

Comment: I don't. I name the severnames after the domains they're running on, of which only moe-desu.com and davixxa.net exist, apart from that one, that is.

Comment: Trying creating a separate access/error log file for that VirtualHost. If the request is truly going to that VirtualHost, then the access and error should show in those specific logs and not main Apache logs.

Comment: BTW, you have checked permissions on the directories? Are you using SELinux? What is the exact error message in the error log.

Comment: By that, I'd just do ? `ErrorLog /path/to/log.log` and ? `CustomLog /path/to/log2.log` right?

Comment: The Log is saying: "Client denied by server configuration". Haven't checked permissions yet. No clue whether or not we're using SELinux, asked my friend, who's the one hosting it.

Comment: Permission output: drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Oct 18 23:19 www-atchannel

Comment: "drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct 18 23:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Oct 17 18:07 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  416 Oct 18 23:19 access.log
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Oct 17 18:00 atchannel
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  222 Oct 17 16:36 atchannel.wsgi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  421 Oct 18 23:19 error.log"

Comment: Regarding SELinux status, he said that unless that's mandatory under Debian 8, that it shouldn't be. Common SELinux commands, as per Google aren't running either, so I assume no.

Comment: If you are using Apache 2.4, do not use Order/Allow directives, use just ``Require all granted``. That is new way of doing things and maybe because using old the precedence of how new/old are applied it may not be accepting the old.

Comment: What about allow from all? Is that to be removed as well?

Comment: Tried both with and without Allow from all. Same result

Comment: ``Require all granted`` replaces the two lines with ``Allow`` and ``Order`` in that context. Can you update the question with the exact ``VirtualHost`` configuration you currently have after all the changes you have made.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: That still is not using the directory path that I said in this answer to use. It will not work with the directory path you have. You need to use the directory path this answer had. That is, change ``/var/www-atchannel/atchannel`` to ``/var/www-atchannel``. It has to be the directory the WSGI script file is in.

Comment: Still does not fix it, using said directory path.

Comment: Fix up example in question with the correction. Cut and paste it from your actual configuration file rather than editing in place. Also, what happens if you try and access a static file under the ``/static`` URL.

Comment: In this case, I picked an image, which did load off the site properly.

Comment: Also. Fixed question

Comment: Do you have an ``Alias / /something`` directive anywhere in your Apache configuration file outside of the VirtualHost.

Comment: There's a `Alias /doc/ /usr/share/doc` alias and a `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ on two other servers. But no. Nothing that aliases root out.

Comment: The only thing there is is:
`<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None` in two generic webservers. But that's not an alias statement.

Comment: Try ``WSGIScriptAlias /subdir /var/www-atchannel/atchannel.wsgi`` and access Python web app at sub URL instead of root of site. Also, no rewrite rules, or redirect directives?

Comment: Changing the WSGIScriptAlias to /chan reveals an internal server error. Updating code in question now

Comment: Which implies something else where in Apache configuration is hijacking ``/`` and doing something with it.

Comment: Seems like it's the apache debian default page, which is not listed with the other sites enabled. Do you know where to find/disable that?

Comment: On CentOS there is a ``conf.d/welcome.conf`` file which has similar default splash page if ``DocumentRoot`` directory has non ``index.html``. I have never encountered anyone having problems with those default splash pages before though. Search for ``ErrorDocument 403`` in all the conf files. I mention CentOS as don't have Debian system handy.

Comment: We somehow got past the 403 Error. It involved me breaking Apache completely, to the point where it wouldn't even restart, and then looking at system logs. Now all other sites are running, and we've progressed to the Internal Server Error stage. Updating my code in the post now.

Comment: That, in theory solved our original question, though, We'd sincerely appreciate any help getting it fully up and running. We're currently trying on our own. Will keep you updated, if you want to still help us, that is.

Comment: We found the solution. It was trying to run Python2 instead of Python3.